# bash script/pgrep not working as expected

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that tries to call pgrep with arguments (Over simplified):

```
PATTERN="'/opt/apps/bin/lighttpd.bin -f /opt/apps/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf\$'"
pgrep -f $PATTERN
echo pgrep -f $PATTERN
```

Gives the following output:

```
Usage: pgrep [-cflvx] [-d DELIM] [-n|-o] [-P PPIDLIST] [-g PGRPLIST] [-s SIDLIST]
        [-u EUIDLIST] [-U UIDLIST] [-G GIDLIST] [-t TERMLIST] [PATTERN]
pgrep -f '/opt/apps/bin/lighttpd.bin -f /opt/apps/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf$'
```

I suppose it means the argument is not passed to pgrep but is passed to echo for some reason.

What I'm expecting:

```
7632
pgrep -f '/opt/apps/bin/lighttpd.bin -f /opt/apps/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf$'
```

When I run the preg line by itself, it outputs 7632 as expected.

Am I doing something wrong here? I've tried with sh, dash and bash. Same outcomes, I really don't see the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to surround ***PATTERN*** in double quotes:

```
PATTERN="/opt/apps/bin/lighttpd.bin -f /opt/apps/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf\$"
pgrep -f "$PATTERN"
```

See: [quoting variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)

*Edit:* and for echoing i would just do:

```
echo pgrep -f \'$PATTERN\'
```

Comment: +1 for double quoting and dropping the single quotes from inside the pattern string.  However, you should probably point out the second change too.

Comment: Edit: Sorry, stackoverflow submitted my comment instead of inserting a newline...   Your solution works, thank you! Could you explain to me why '' works when I run the command at the prompt but in my script it requires "" ? Thank you

Comment: @alex: this happens because `PATTERN` doesn't contain literal quote symbols after assignment (they rather indicate that whole expression is single string); to keep treating this expression as a single string, you need to quote it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

As I don't have lighttpd.bin available to test with, I am submitting an untested option, mostly agreeing with @barti_ddu, but with a slightly different twist

```
PATTERN='/opt/apps/bin/lighttpd.bin -f /opt/apps/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf\$'
pgrep  -f "$PATTERN"
echo pgrep  -f "$PATTERN"
```

I would keep the single quotes on the assingment to PATTERN, but totally agree you need the dbl-quoting when using with pgrep or echo.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The usage message from `pgrep` shown includes `-f` without any argument.